# Missing Extract Type on Data Extract Activity. Why my account is missing this feature?

Tags: marketing-cloud, tracking-extract

Can anyone help me figure out why I am missing the "Tracking Extract" feature in my account.[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is one of those things you need to request from Support. Create a case for this.